# Airflow: Best way to store a value in Airflow task that could be retrieved in the recurring task runs

Tags: python, airflow

In Airflow for a DAG, I'm writing a monitoring task which will run again and again until a certain condition is met. In this task, when some event happened, I need to store the timestamp and retrieve this value in next task run (for the same task) and update it again if required.

What's the best way to store this value?

So far I have tried below approaches to store:

- storing in xcoms, but this value couldn't be retried in next task run as the xcom variable gets deleted for each new task run for the same DAG run.
- storing in Airflow Variables - this solves the purpose, I could store, update, delete as needed, but it doesn't look clean for my use case as lot of new Variables are getting generated per DAG and we have over 2k DAGs (pipelines).
- global variables in the python class, but the value gets overridden in next task run.

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you have task that is re-run with the same "Execution Date", using Airflow Variables is your best choice. XCom will be deleted by definition when you re-run the same task with the same execution date and it won't change.

Basically what you want to do is to store the "state" of task execution and it's kinda "against" Airflow's principle of idempotent tasks (where re-running the task should produce "final" results of running the task every time you run it. You want to store the state of the task between re-runs on the other hand and have it behave differently with subsequent re-runs - based on the stored state.

Another option that you could use, is to store the state in an external storage (for example object in S3). This might be better in case of performance if you do not want to load your DB too much. You could come up with a "convention" of naming of such state object and pull it a start and push when you finish the task.

Comment: Thanks @Jarek Potiuk for your comments. We have already implemented this with Airflow Variables but because of overhead of having too many Variables getting created (one Variable per DAG and over 2k DAGs) is concerning to us. So we're looking for an alternate approach.

Comment: Also storing the state in an external storage could be a costly affair as our task reruns every few mins for monitoring, but I'll check on this. Thanks again.

Comment: Well.  You have to pay the price. Airflow is a distributed system - each task runs potentially ona different machine. So unless you use Local Executor (there all tasks run on single machine and can use local storage for storing the state) you somehow HAVE TO be able to move state information from one machine to the other. It might be shared database or external storage or even mounted shared drive - but there is no free lunch :). The state has to move over the network from one node to all other nodes (or in optimised way to those nodes that need the information) . No matter how hard you try th

Answer (score 0):

You could use XComs with `include_prior_dates` parameter. [Docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/taskinstance/index.html#airflow.models.taskinstance.TaskInstance.xcom_pull) state the following:

> **include_prior_dates** (bool) -- If False, only XComs from the current execution_date are returned. If True, XComs from previous dates are returned as well.

(Default value is `False`)

Then you would do:  `xcom_pull(task_ids='previous_task', include_prior_dates=True)`

I haven't tried out personally but looks like this may be a good solution to your case.

Comment: Thanks @NicoE for suggestion, but it's not working for my use case. My task gets called/executed again and again; for every task run I need to store a value and retrieve this value in next task run. With xcom approach, this variable in xcom is getting deleted for the next task run.